# How do I use “Get Contents of URL” in an iOS Home app automation?

Tags: ios, tvos, homekit, ipados, ios-homekit

I want to use use my Apple TV 4K to make a daily call to a web URL; much like a `cron` Job if I had a home server. In theory, this should be so simple:

- Open iOS **Home** app
- Go to the **Automation** tab
- Create a new automation
- Choose `A Time of Day Occurs`
- Select `Next`
- Choose `Advanced -> Convert To Shortcut`
- Tap the ➕ icon
- Choose `Web`
- Choose `Get Contents of URL` from the Web Requests section
- Enter the URL as `https://apple.com`
- Tap the ▶️ icon to test the automation

I see the error message “A server with the specified hostname could not be found.”

Can anyone explain to me how one might use this feature if its not capable of resolving domain names?

[image: iPadOS Home App]

Comment: Related question: if it won’t run on my Apple TV, can I use my iPhone? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722563/ios-shortcuts-will-a-time-of-day-personal-automation-run-if-the-phone-s-not-b

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer: create the automation in the Shortcuts app (not the Home app) and this will work.